# Что такое .net, для чего это нужно и где применяется

Tags: .net, php

Очень интересно, что такое .net, для чего это нужно и где применяется.
Так же, недавно увидел, что .net поддерживает PHP. Что вы думаете о этой связке? Стоит ли изучать .net для использования с Пыхой?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [Что это такое](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Более подробно, чем в Вики я не опишу при всем желании
2. Нужно для разработки бизнес-(и не только бизнес)приложений  под Windows, а также web-приложений, web-сервисов и всего такого прочего. Удобен широчайшей инфраструктурой, наборами классов на все случаи жизни, огромной системой документации, средств разработки. В последние годы сам .NET Framework устанавливается вместе с Windows и по сути неотделим от него
3. Ничего не думаем, поскольку выглядит это не более, чем занятной поделкой, и тратить на этот Пых.NET свое время вряд ли имеет смысл. Сам .NET более чем замечательно существует без PHP, а PHP в свою очередь ничуть не менее замечательно существует без .NET (который, между прочим, не слишком-то кросплатформенный). Если уж так сложилось, что вас интересуют и PHP и .NET, то изучать их имеет смысл по отдельности

Comment: Выходит, что бы изучать .net не нужны дополнительные языки? Или как?
Мне всегда казалось, что .net используется только с каким - нибудь языком. К примеру, C#.

Comment: .NET -это не язык. Это платформа, на которой могут базироваться другие языки. Для этой платформы есть своеобразный ассемблер CIL, в который преобразуеются код, написанный на любом из .NET-языков. То есть для работы с .NET вам нужен какой-то язык, чаще всего это C# или Visual Basic, хотя есть и другие варианты

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.